# Giving an object property a random property value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a tile based game and want to give each type of tile a random color, for example:

```
Game.Glyph = function(properties) {
    properties = properties || {};
    this._char = properties['character'] || ' ';
    this._foreground = properties['foreground'] || 'white';
};

Game.Tile.floorTile = new Game.Tile({
    character: '.',
});
```

And then assuming I've populated a `map` array with `Game.Tile.floorTile`(among others)

```
for (let x = 0; x < this._width; x++) {
            for (let y = 0; y < this._height; y++) {
                if (map[x][y] == Game.Tile.floorTile) {
                    map[x][y]._foreground = ['red','yellow'].random();
            }

     }
}
```

This results in every floor tile being either red or yellow, not a random distribution. How can I give each tile a random color like I'm trying above?

Comment: There is no `random()` method in JS Array prototype

Comment: I have an implementation I'm using, should have mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only want to chose between two values a [ternary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) makes this easy combined with `Math.random()` which produces a values between 0 and 1:

```
map[x][y]._foreground = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'red': 'yellow'
```

For example with a simplified version of your code:

```js
let map = [[{}, {}],[{}, {}]]

for (let x = 0; x < 2; x++) {
    for (let y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
            map[x][y]._foreground = Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'red': 'yellow'
    }

}
console.log(map)
```

Comment: Thanks the ternary is pretty neat. However I till have my original problem where every floor tile becomes either yellow or red, not a random mixture of the two.

Comment: Are you seeing that what you run the snippet above @AlwaysNeedingHelp?

Comment: No which is strange - when I change the color of a single floorTile every other floor tile changes color as well.

Comment: @AlwaysNeedingHelp it sound like you might have populated your matrix with a bunch of references to one instance of `Game.Tile`. When you create the matrix you need to make call `new Game.Tile()` for each element of the array.

Comment: You're right :) Took me a while to refactor but thanks for pointing me in the right direction ^.^